# xmlbeans classes created by maven are not placed in the right package structure

Tags: maven-plugin

I'm using xmlbeans to generate some java classes. I'm using maven 3 in my project.
I have included the dependency and the plugin details as shown below.

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>xmlbeans-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>xmlbeans</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <schemaDirectory>src/main/xsd</schemaDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

When I run a clean package goal I get compiler errors simply because the classes which uses the xmlbeans generated reference are not found in the classpath. This is because the xmlbeans classes are not compiled into the right directory structure. rather it just places it in the target\classes\aseXMLR30 (where as it should be in the formal structure ex: com.ex.first)

I have googled and read many blogs nothing helped me so far!
any replies/answers are really appreciated!

Answer (score 11):

I know this question is 4 months old but in case you and/or others are still looking for a solution, [this blog post](http://www.subshell.com/en/subshell/blog/article-Changing-from-m2eclipse-to-m2e-Eclipse-Indigo100.html) may be able to provide a clue.

Essentially, what it says is that all references to `org.maven.ide.eclipse` should be replaced by `org.eclipse.m2e`. It references `.launch` files but to be on the safer side just grep recursively through your Eclipse directory and projects.